# Android WIFIP2P - JSON String changed from Client Side

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good Day,

I have a problem when receiving JSON from HOST to Client Device. When Sending Massive JSON(5-10mb size) to Client, the received JSON string cut off and other characters or string changed.

Example:
Host:
`{"route":{"testing":"yes"}`

Client Received message: `{"rote":{"testig`

Is there any method on how I can still same message JSON string from Host to Client handle message?